# ciclo foreach y next si se cumple una condicion ayuda en ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ciclo `foreach` y `next` si se cumple una condición, estoy analizando una línea en un *txt* y quiero verificar si la próxima línea cumple con un patrón para hacer una cosa y si no hacer otra cosa.

Ejemplo:

```
next if line.include?("UNSS")
if next line.start('UNSS') or next line.start('CNT')
```

Aunque no me da error no me da el resultado esperado, se que es algo básico pero me surgió un error a ultima hora en desarrollo y interpretar de esa manera.

Mi intención es luego de verificar que la presente línea empiece por un patrón y verificar si la próxima tiene un patrón para saber si llego al final o no para luego guardar.

Supongamos que tengo las siguientes estructura: introducir el código aquí

Y este otro:

```
LIN00000108410036009090EN 
IMDF  CU ESPUM FREIXENET C.NEGRO 12G BOT 750
QTY 21000000000000002CS 
QTY129000000000000006SIN
MOA203000000000055514.00
PRIAAA000000042968.00LIUCS 
ALCA  DE1
PCD  10000024.00
MOA204000000000010313.00
ALCA  DE1
PCD  10000015.00
MOA204000000000004899.00
ALCC  CA1
MOA 23000000000001080.00
aqui la proxima linea puede ser un LIN o UNSS
```

Supongamos que estoy en la linea `PRIAAA000000042968.00LIUCS`
(una vez que estoy acá quiero saber si mi próxima línea empieza por `ALCA` o si empieza por `UNSS`), ya que si empieza por `UNSS` es una formato diferente y necesito guardar en ese momento, pero si no es quiero dejar que siga y guarde en `MOA 23`.

```
  a = Array.new
a = File.read(item)
oc = a.split("\n") 
#File.foreach(item).with_object([]) do |line, result|

 oc.each_cons(2) do |line, line2|
       puts "procensando linea #{line} ..."        



      if line.start_with?('LIN') # indica el numero item y codigo
                @cproducto = line[9..-2]
                @numeroitem = line[7..8]
                @numeroitem2 = @numeroitem.to_s
      end          
      line.start_with?('IMD') #indica la descripcion
                @desproducto = line[8..-1]
      if line.start_with?('QTY 21')  # indica la cantidad pedida y el tipo de unidad de caja                      
                @cantidadpedida = line[19..20]              
                @caja   = line[-3..-1]
                pedido = '?????????????????????'
      end          
      if line.start_with?('QTY129') # cantidad de unidades que trae una caja
                @cantidadunidades = line[-6..-4]                               
                @tunidad = 'Unidades Simples'
                #Detalle.last.destroy 
      end                                 
      if line.start_with?('MOA203') #precio neto del producto               
                @precioneto = line[7..-1] # not [-10..-1
                @precioneto2 = @precioneto.to_f.round(3).to_f 
      end                       
      if line.start_with?('MOA 204')
                 if !flagmoa
                @valordescu1 = line[-10..-1]
                flagmoa = true                
                else                                            #monto del descuento pueden haber hasta dos descuentos en una oc          
                @valordescu2 = line[-10..-1]
                end
      end

      if line.start_with?('PRIAAA') #precio neto de lista de precio por unidad
                pedido = line[-3..-1]
                @valorcd = line[-16..-8]  
               if  line.start_with?("ALCA")
                    # código para líneas que empiezan con "ALCA"
               elsif line2.start_with?("UNSS")
                @p.detalles.create!(cod_prod: @cproducto, descripcion: @desproducto, numero_item: @numeroitem2, cantidad_pedida: @cantidadpedida , precio_unit: @precioneto2 , tipo_caja: @cantidadunidades ,  total_linea: @precioneto2, p_descu1: @porcentaje , monto_descu1: @valordescu1, p_descu2: @porcentaje2, monto_descu2:@valordescu2 , p_cargo1:"" , monto_cargo1: @valorcargo)           
               end

      end      

      if line.start_with?('PCD')   
            if !flagpcd
              @porcentaje   = line[-6..-1] 
              flagpcd = true
            else
            @porcentaje2   = line[-6..-1]
            end
      end      
      if line.start_with?('MOA 204')
                 if !flagmoa
                @valordescu11 = line[-10..-1]
                @valordescu1 = @valordescu1.to_s
                flagmoa = true                
                else                                            #monto del descuento pueden haber hasta dos descuentos en una oc          
                @valordescu22 = line[-10..-1]
                @valordescu2 = @valordescu22.to_s
                end      
      end         # 

      if line.start_with?('MOA 23') # or line.start_with?('UNSS') #valor en monto del cargo
               @tcargo = 'Cargo'
               @valorcargo = line[-10..-1] 
           @p.detalles.create!(cod_prod: @cproducto, descripcion: @desproducto, numero_item: @numeroitem2, cantidad_pedida: @cantidadpedida , precio_unit: @precioneto2 , tipo_caja: @cantidadunidades ,  total_linea: @precioneto2, p_descu1: @porcentaje , monto_descu1: @valordescu1, p_descu2: @porcentaje2, monto_descu2:@valordescu2 , p_cargo1:"" , monto_cargo1: @valorcargo)         
           flagpcd = false
           flagmoa = false  
      end
```

[image: anexo error]

Comment: ¿Si la línea 1 cumple con una condición, entonces checas la línea 2 por otra condición?, ¿luego lo mismo con la 2 y 3 respectivamente o te vas directo a la 3 y 4? ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo más completo para entender mejor?

Comment: @gerry ya modifique la pregunta, para su mayor compresion.

Comment: ¿La línea `PRIAAA000000042968.00LIUCS` cumple con alguna condición particular?, ¿o simplemente es el ejemplo de una validación que debes hacer en todas las líneas? O bien, viendo tu problema desde otra perspectiva: Si alguna línea empieza con `UNSS` entonces guardas la línea anterior, ¿es correcto? En caso que así sea, ¿qué pasa con las que empiezan con `ALCA`?

Comment: @gerry Siempre empieza por `PRIAA` ese es el patron. de esa linea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que las líneas están en la variable `lines` (como colección), podrías utilizar [`Enumerable#each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons); por ejemplo:

```
lines.each_cons(2) do |current_line, next_line|
  if current_line.start_with?("PRIAA")
    if next_line.start_with?("ALCA")
      # código para líneas que empiezan con "ALCA"
    elsif next_line.start_with?("UNSS")
      # código para líneas que empiezan con "UNSS"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: current_line, este nombres aleatorio o es parte de ruby para señalar la linea actual?

Comment: me dice `método undefined each_cons 'para" UNB7807910CL000178000M0CL0001 \ n ": string`

Comment: `current_line` es solo un nombre de variable, puedes usar el que quieras. El método `each_cons` debes ejecutarlo con una colección (e.g. un arreglo) pero lo estás llamando en un _string_.

Comment: ya solucione el problema del array ahora me da otro error nil class pero es raro-- antes me guardaba. actualice mi pregunta con una imagen y mi codigo quizas tengo algo mal una vez mas gracias

Comment: @JonathanZambrano ¿En qué línea del código se presenta el error? Pareciera que `line2` en algún momento está vacía (i.e. `nil`).

Comment: ya solucione con tu codigo mil pero mil gracias... muy atento..